# Unique hash as authorization for endpoint

Tags: security, encryption

I've already saw, that sometimes companies are sending customized links to get to some resource without logging in.

For example some company send me email with link to my invoices:

```
www.financial.service.com/<SOME_HASHED_VALUE>
```

and there is no any authorization behind this endpoint, they only rely on fact that I am only person who knows this hash value. I have very similar case but I have concerns:

firstly is it good approach ?

secondly how should I make this hash? sha512 on some random data?

Comment: In regards to random number generation, make sure to use a CSPRNG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator. A lot of the random generation functions built into languages are not cryptographically secure and can be predicted.

Comment: A hash of random data is just random data. Applying a hash doesn't achieve anything in that case. (But totally agreed that any random data needs to come from a CSPRNG. That ideally would go without saying, but it does need to be said.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a completely valid approach, and is its own type of authentication. If constructed correctly, it proves that you have access to that email (it doesn't prove anything else, but it does prove that much).

These values often aren't hashes. They're often random, and that's their power. If they are hashes, they need to be constructed such that their output is "effectively random," so usually you might as well just make them random in the first place. For this discussion, I'll call it a "token."

The point of a token is that's unpredictable, and extremely sparse within its search space. By unpredictable, I mean that even if I know exactly who the token is for, it should be effectively impossible (i.e. within practical time contraints) to construct a legitimate token for that user. So, for instance, if this were the hash of the username and a timestamp (even a millisecond timestamp), that would be a terrible token. I could guess those very quickly. So random is best.

By "sparse" I mean that out of all the possible tokens (i.e. strings of the correct length and format), a vanishingly small number of them should be valid tokens, and those valid tokens should be scattered across the search space randomly. For example, if the tokens were sequential, that would be terrible. If I had a token, I could find other tokens by simply increasing or decreasing the value by one.

So a good token looks like this:

- Select a random, long string
- Store it in your database, along with metadata about what it means, and a timestamp
- When a user shows up with it, read the data from the database
- After some period of time, expire the token by deleting it from the database (optional, but preferred)

Another way to implement this kind of scheme is to encode the encrypted metadata (i.e. the userid, what page this goes to, a timestamp, etc). Then you don't need to store anything in a database, because its right there in the URL. I don't usually like this approach because it requires a very high-value crypto key that you then have to protect on production servers, and can be used to connect as anyone. Even if I have good ways to protect such a key (generally an attached HSM), I don't like such a key even existing. So generally I prefer a database. But for some applications, encrypting the data is better. Storing the metadata in the URL also significantly restricts how much metadata you can store, so again, tokens are nicer.

Comment: At the moment I am using

    sha512(Random.alphaNumeric(60))

It generates hash of length 128, so it will be extremly hard to brute force it. The endpoint looks like

    www.domain/report/{hash}

And there is no authorization beyond that hash in link. This report contains very confidential data I wonder if it fullfill security requirments

Comment: If you're happy with a 128 alpha-numeric token, I'd recommend `Random.alphaNumeric(128)` over hashing a 60-character key. 36^128 is a full 662 bits of entropy rather than spreading 311 bits (36^60) of entropy over a 512-bit space. (Your way is almost certainly fine; it's just that adding the hash is making things worse rather than better.)

Comment: As to whether it fulfills the security requirement, that completely depends on what the security requirement is. This information is not protected from anyone who has access to the link, which I assume you send over unencrypted email. So that is not as good as a user authenticating with a secret password. But *that* isn't as good as having the user come in person and identify themselves with government id. But *that* isn't as good as… There's always more I can do and there are trade-offs (and sometimes unintended consequences). It all depends on your full situation.

Answer (score 1):

> and there is no any authorization behind this endpoint, they only rely on fact that I am only person who knows this hash value.

Usually there is authorization before accessing the endpoint (you have authenticated before receiving the invoices). I see it as a common way to share resource with external parties. We use similar approach with expirable AWS S3 urls.

> firstly is it good approach ?

It depends on your use case. For sharing some internal resources with option to control access (revoking access, time based access, one time access, ..)

> secondly how should I make this hash? sha512 on some random data?

Until the *SOME_HASHED_VALUE* is not guessable with negligible collision probability (salted hash, long random unique value,  ..) it should be ok.